# Proper way to allow overflowing nested flexbox child to scroll?

Tags: html, css, scroll, flexbox, overflow

I have this layout and I am trying to get the inner red child element to be scrolled instead of overflowing its parent:

[image: overflowing child]

I found a seemingly hacky way to do this - I got the layout I wanted by setting `overflow-y: hidden` (auto also works) on both the grandparent and on the great grandparent:

[image]

Here is my code (and here is a convenient jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2zw3qng7/5/):

```html
<div id="greatgreatgrandparent">
  <div id="greatgrandparent">
    greatgrandparent
    <div id="grandparent">
      grandparent
      <div id="parent">
        parent
        <div id="child">
          <div>child</div>
          <div>child</div>
          <div>child</div>
          <div>child</div>
          <div>child</div>
          <div>child</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="granduncle">
      granduncle
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
div {
  padding: 16px;
}

#greatgreatgrandparent {
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#greatgrandparent {
  background: greenyellow;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
}

#grandparent {
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* overflow-y: hidden; */
}

#parent {
  flex: 1;
  background: orange;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#child {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  height: 2000px;
}

#granduncle {
  background: purple;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this? It's not intuitive to me that I need to set `overflow: hidden` (or auto) on the grandparent and great-grandparent nodes - I would have expected just setting `overflow: scroll` on the parent node would be enough to get the child to scroll and have the parent grow to fill its flex container. It's weird to me that setting `overflow: hidden` on an ancestor node actually affects a decedent node's height.

This is a simplified version of my actual layout which has many more flexbox nodes in the middle. It's a pain to plumb `overflow: hidden` through all these nodes to get my child node to scroll.

Is there a better way to do this? Or am I doing it the proper way?

Comment: Just add `* { min-height: 0 }` to your code. https://jsfiddle.net/gh98sfjn/

Comment: Thanks, this works a charm. The linked "duplicate" question above explains why the default `min-height` of elements is `auto` which sizes them to their children - which was a breaking change from the previous default behavior to have `min-height: 0` and `min-width: 0`. Setting `overflow-y: hidden` on a parent works because that turns the parent into a "scroll container" and scroll containers get a default min size of 0. Spec: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#min-size-auto